# Merge objects from the same array by two with different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of doubles

```
const data = [
-0.003,-8.178509172818559E-16,
0.002,-1.3576469946421737E-15,
0.007,-1.2329107629591376E-1]
```

and I want to use them in react-vis.

The syntax for data to insert in react-vis is

```
                        {x: -0.003, y: -8.178509172818559E-16},
                        {x: 0.002, y: -1.3576469946421737E-15},
```

I want to make the same.

So I made the indexes and then assign an x and y values

```
    let preparedData = Object.assign({}, data);
    let preparedData2 = Object.keys(preparedData).map((keyName =>
    {
        const newKey = keyName % 2 === 0 ? 'x' : 'y';
        return { [newKey] : preparedData[keyName] };
    }));
```

So my array looks like:

```
0: {x: -0.003}
1: {y: -8.178509172818559e-16}
2: {x: 0.002}
3: {y: -1.3576469946421737e-15}
4: {x: 0.007}
```

and I want to group them by x and y without the usage of side-libraries.
I tried reduce with no luck, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect x and y, alternatively.

```js
const data = [
  -0.003,
  -8.178509172818559e-16,
  0.002,
  -1.3576469946421737e-15,
  0.007,
  -1.2329107629591376e-1
];
// Using for Loop:

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  const xy = { x: data[i], y: data[i + 1] };
  result.push(xy);
}
console.log(result);

// Using reduce.

const result1 = data.reduce((arr, xy, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    const data = { x: xy };
    arr.push(data);
  } else {
    arr[Math.floor(index / 2)].y = xy;
  }
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(result1);
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: great, THANK YOU! Just a question:  const data = { x: xy }; - what does it mean? Where x comes from?

Answer (score 0):

You could slice two items, destructure the array to `x` and `y` and take short hand properties for the object for pushing.

```js
var data = [-0.003, -8.178509172818559E-16, 0.002, -1.3576469946421737E-15, 0.007, -1.2329107629591376E-1],
    result = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    let [x, y] = data.slice(i, i += 2);
    result.push({ x, y });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A short approach.

```js
var data = [-0.003, -8.178509172818559E-16, 0.002, -1.3576469946421737E-15, 0.007, -1.2329107629591376E-1],
    result = data.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        (r[i >> 1] = r[i >> 1] || {})['xy'[i % 2]] = v;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you, nice, but loop is not ES6 style, I mean effective but not modern. Thank you!

Comment: thank you for your effort! This one is too complicated for my simple mind ;0